# Why @ViewScoped Managed Bean's @PostConstruct init() method never called?

Tags: jsf-2.2, java-ee-7

I am newbie to JSF/Java ee7 and tried to test some features to understand how things work.
I used templating for testing purposes. Here is the relevant JSF template client:

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:panelGroup class="keret" id="tartalom">
        <h:form id="email" rendered="#{emailManagedBean.urlap}">
            <h:messages/>
            <h:outputLabel for="emailbox" value="Add meg az email címed, és juss hozzá bestsellerünkhöz 5Ft-ért"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{emailManagedBean.newEmail.email}"/>
            <h:commandButton actionListener="#{emailManagedBean.saveEmail()}" value="Mentés">
                <f:ajax immediate="true" execute="@form" render=":tartalom"/>
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
        <h:panelGroup id="szoveg" rendered="#{not emailManagedBean.urlap}">
            <h3>Köszönjük!</h3>
            <p>
                Hamarosan emailt fogsz kapni tőlünk. Kérlek, ellenőrizd a levélszemét, illetve spam mappákban is a tőlünk kapott levelet. A levlében lévő linkre kattintva hozzájuthatsz az ajándékodhoz.
            </p>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:define>
```

My managed bean:

```
@Named(value = "emailManagedBean")
@ViewScoped
public class emailManagedBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    EmailsFacadeLocal emailFacade;

    private Emailcamp newEmail;

    private boolean urlap;

    public Emailcamp getNewEmail() {
        return newEmail;
    }

    public void setNewEmail(Emailcamp newEmail) {
        this.newEmail = newEmail;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        newEmail = new Emailcamp();
        urlap=true;
    }

    public boolean isUrlap() {
        return urlap;
    }

    public void setUrlap(boolean urlap) {
        this.urlap = urlap;
    }


    public void validateEmail(FacesContext context, UIComponent comp,
        Object value) {

        String input = (String) value;
        EmailValidator validator = EmailValidator.getInstance();
        if (!validator.isValid(input)) {
            ((UIInput) comp).setValid(false);
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(
                "Helytelen email cím formátum");
            context.addMessage(null, message);
        } else {
            if(!emailFacade.exist(newEmail.getEmail())){
                ((UIInput) comp).setValid(true);
            }
            else {
                context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Már megadtad korábban az email címed"));
            }
        }
    }

    public void saveEmail() {
        /*Get current date and time*/
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        newEmail.setRecemaildate(c.getTime());

        /*Get Referral*/
        HttpServletRequest hr = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        newEmail.setReferer((hr.getHeader("referer")==null) ? "not available" : hr.getHeader("referer") );
        newEmail.setStatus(Status.NOT_SENT.toString());
        emailFacade.create(newEmail);
        urlap=false;
    }
}
```

The expected behavior is that the init function set urlap boolean variable to true so the h:form should be shown as there is conditional rendering on the view side.
Later the customer clicks on Save ("Mentés") and the new email address and some data will be stored in a database. After the ajax call I urlap boolean varaible is set to false  not to render the form again but render a thank you message.
Unfortunately the init function is never called so the boolean variable never set to true. As a consequences my thanks message is shown without collecting the email.
The second strange thing which is the consequence of the ajax component (I guess) that I got an error message: outputScript with no library, no name, and no body content. I did not declare any outputScript in my xhtml.

Comment: What package is the `@ViewScoped` imported from?

Comment: @kolosus Your question was an answer to me. I realized that I imported the wrong package: 'javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped'. As I changed it to 'javax.faces.view.ViewScoped' it worked.
By now I have only one problem regarding the error message: outputScript with no library, no name, and no body content. It is not related to the scope issue

Comment: Ask another question